# Ionic Firebase GooglePlus Auth

Tags: firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, google-plus-signin

I am developing a Google authentication for my app
I got a problem when I chose the Google users, the app doesn't log in
and I see in the firebase Database is doesn't add the account.
the prompt when the emulator is running works but when I click nothing happens.

```
 export class LoginPage {
  form: FormGroup;
  loginError: string;
  userProfile: any = null;
  constructor(
    public googleplus: GooglePlus,
    private navCtrl: NavController,
    private auth: AuthService,
    fb: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.form = fb.group({
      email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.email])],
      password: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(6)])]
    });
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( user => {
      if (user){
        this.userProfile = user;
      } else {
        this.userProfile = null;
      }
    });
  }

  signInWithGoogle() {
    this.googleplus.login({
      'webClientId': 'MYID3842ETC.apps.googleusercontent.com',
      'offline': true
    }).then( (res) => {
      if (!firebase.auth().currentUser) {
        firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider.credential(res.idToken))
          .then(() =>
            this.navCtrl.push(TabsPage)
          )
      }
    })
  }
```

HTML

```
  <button ion-button clear full color="light" (click)="signInWithGoogle()" *ngIf="userProfile">
            <ion-icon name="logo-googleplus"></ion-icon>
            Login with Google
          </button>
```

NPM installed

`npm install --save @ionic-native/google-plus`

and

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Console errors:

> D/CordovaActivity: Incoming Result. Request code = 77552 D/CordovaInterfaceImpl: Sending activity result to plugin I/GooglePlugin: In onActivityResult I/GooglePlugin: One of our activities finished up I/GooglePlugin: Handling SignIn Result I/GooglePlugin: Wasn't signed in D/CordovaActivity: Resumed the activity. D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js: Line 1704 : ERROR I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1704)] "ERROR", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js (1704)

Comment: any errors in the console?

Comment: D/CordovaActivity: Incoming Result. Request code = 77552
D/CordovaInterfaceImpl: Sending activity result to plugin
I/GooglePlugin: In onActivityResult
I/GooglePlugin: One of our activities finished up
I/GooglePlugin: Handling SignIn Result
I/GooglePlugin: Wasn't signed in
D/CordovaActivity: Resumed the activity.
D/SystemWebChromeClient: file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js: Line 1704 : ERROR
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(1704)] "ERROR", source: file:///android_asset/www/build/vendor.js (1704)